# Trying to get my code to update a players score in noughts and crosses if the two players were to draw

Tags: python

essentially I've tried a couple of things but it either prints, the players score with no updated score or Condradultions message with the draw message and updated scores. So not sure how to get it to Print the draw message and updated scores separately with the congratulations score. If more info is needed let me know. Thank you

```
    if GameHasBeenWon:  # Update scores and display result
        if (PlayerOneSymbol == CurrentSymbol):
            print(PlayerOneName + " congratulations you win!")
            PlayerOneScore += 1
        elif print(PlayerTwoName + " congratulations you win!"):
            PlayerTwoScore += 1
        else:
            print("A draw this time!")
            PlayerOneScore += float(0.5)
            PlayerTwoScore += float(0.5)

    print("\n")
    print(PlayerOneName + ", your score is: " + str(PlayerOneScore))
    print(PlayerTwoName + ", your score is: " + str(PlayerTwoScore))
    print();
```

Comment: "If more info is needed let me know". Yes, you need this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example At this point we don't see where you try to print the scores.

Comment: I've added the part in where I print the scores

Answer (score 2):

You have `print` statement as condition:

```
elif print(PlayerTwoName + " congratulations you win!"):
    ...
```

`print` returns `None`, thats why this block of code will never execute.

I guess the correct condition would be

```
if PlayerTwoSymbol == CurrentSymbol:
    print(PlayerTwoName + " congratulations you win!")
    PlayerTwoScore += 1
...
```